# Python and Regex - extracting a number from a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex, and I'm starting to sort of get the hang of things.  I have a string that looks like this:

> This is a generated number #123 which is an integer.

The text that I've shown here around the 123 will always stay exactly the same, but it may have further text on either side.  But the number may be 123, 597392, really one or more digits.  I believe I can match the number and the folowing text using using `\d+(?= which is an integer.)`, but how do I write the look-behind part?

When I try `(?<=This is a generated number #)\d+(?= which is an integer.)`, it does not match using regexpal.com as a tester.

Also, how would I use python to get this into a variable (stored as an int)?

NOTE: I *only* want to find the numbers that are sandwiched in between the text I've shown.  The string might be much longer with many more numbers.

Comment: Why use look-behind? Just `re.findall("(\d+)(.*?)$", s)` ?

Comment: regexpal.com has issues, then, since your RE succeeds in Python: `import re; c= re.compile(r'(?<=This is a generated number #)\d+(?= which is an integer.)'); c.search(' This is a generated number #123 which is an integer.')` results in a sre.SRE_Match object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a fancy regex. Just use a group on what you want.

```
re.search(r'#(\d+)', 'This is a generated number #123 which is an integer.').group(1)
```

if you want to match a number in the middle of some known text, follow the same rule:

```
r'some text you know (\d+) other text you also know'
```

Comment: I wasn't clear - the string may contain a lot of numbers, but I only want to match on those numbers surrounded by the text I specified.

Comment: So follow what I said. Just add a group for what you need!

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down for me.  I hadn't used groups before, but it makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
res = re.search('#(\d+)', 'This is a generated number #123 which is an integer.')

if res is not None:
    integer = int(res.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the numbers only if the numbers are following text "This is a generated number #" AND followed by " which is an integer.", you don't have to do look-behind and lookahead. You can simply match the whole string, like:

```
"This is a generated number #(\d+) which is an integer."
```

I am not sure if I understood what you really want though. :)

**updated**

```
In [16]: a='This is a generated number #123 which is an integer.'                                                                        

In [17]: b='This should be a generated number #123 which could be an integer.'

In [18]: exp="This is a generated number #(\d+) which is an integer."

In [19]: result =re.search(exp, a)                                                                                                       

In [20]: int(result.group(1))
Out[20]: 123

In [21]: result = re.search(exp,b)

In [22]: result == None
Out[22]: True
```

Comment: This regex would say that this whole string is a match, however.  I really only want to match on the number.

Comment: well I do have group in the expression. you can get the numbers by group. see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the findall() in the re module.

```
string="This is a string that contains #134534 and other things"
match=re.findall(r'#\d+ .+',string);
print match
```

Output would be '#1234534 and other things'

This will match any length number #123 or #123235345 then a space then the rest of the line till it hits a newline char.

Comment: This will match any number in the string, which I don't want.