# fetching values out of multiple brackets

Tags: python, string

I have this string

```
mod = 'ketobutyric_arp_rm(12);oxidation+%28hw%29(19)'
```

and want to get the numbers in parentheses as a list some kind of similar to:

```
mod_pos = ['12','19']
```

Using split seems to be a bit circuitous, and I don't know how to use a find method on this.

Any suggestions how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python and Regex - extracting a number from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507524/python-and-regex-extracting-a-number-from-a-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331/python-extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: Could just use a regex: http://rubular.com/r/rsyO4rZzuS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
>>> import re
>>> mod='ketobutyric_arp_rm(12);oxidation+%28hw%29(19)'
>>> re.findall(r'\((\d+)\)', mod)
['12', '19']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. 
    import re
    m=re.match(r'((\d+))', string)
This would return matched patterns in a tuple which u can fetch by m.group(1) etc..